# How QTcpSocket client can understand that it is in the queue? (and does not go to connected state)

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I am developing a server and client project with Qt. I want to print the connection status for the users. For this propose I use state() like:

```
socketState = mySocket.state();

if (socketState == 3) {
   Print("we have connected");
}
```

However, it does not work when the server queues new connections. To make it clear, my client state is 3 even if the server has paused accepting new connections:

```
//server side: 
myServer->pauseAccepting();

//client side: 
connectToHost()
socketState = mySocket.state();
```

Now the socketState is 3 instead of 0 or a special number for queue state.

To sum it up, I want to know how to inform the client that it is in the queue? Is there anything like state() that has a return value for queue state?

Comment: The client is technically *connected*, as the queue completed the 3-way TCP handshake, even though the server code may not have *accepted* the client yet. So, the only way for the client to know whether it has been *accepted* or not is to start actually communicating with the server and see if it gets a response back. There is no *connected-but-not-accepted* state at the socket layer. A client socket has no concept of a server socket's queue, only whether it is *connected* to the server or not.

Comment: Yes it is true. I used wirte() in server and read() in the client to check the connectivity. When the read() return value (in client side) is 0 it means the client is in the queue and therefore it closes it's socket. This method works fine as long as the first client is still connected. As soon as first client disconnects, the wirte() function in the server does not work anymore. Maybe I need to provide more codes and descriptions to explain the situation.

Comment: "*I used wirte() in server and read() in the client to check the connectivity.*" - having the server send a greeting is a good idea. "*When the read() return value (in client side) is 0 it means the client is in the queue*" - no, it means the server closed the connection. If the client socket is blocking, read() will block until the greeting arrives. If the client socket is non-blocking, read() will fail with EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK until the greeting arrives. "*As soon as first client disconnects, the wirte() function in the server does not work anymore*" - then you are using it wrong.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your comments. Secondly, should I use a new thread to handle the new client (which is in the queue by OS)? Because this server is proposed to handle only one client but, when new clients automatically get connected (in the queue) it looks like I need to start multi threading.

Comment: When a client connects, it sits in the server's queue until the server code accepts the client from the queue, or until the client disconnects while still in the queue. While the client is in the queue, you don't need to do anything with it, nor can you anyway. You have to accept the client before you can do anything with it. You would need multiple threads only if you intend to service multiple accepted clients at the same time, and even then only if you are using blocking sockets - you can handle multiple non-blocking sockets without needing to use multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find the answer.

The refused client that goes to the queue (by OS) is not different with other clients. Therefore, we can make a special socket for it (which means it is NOT in queue anymore) and start communication (inform and close).

for example:

```
QTcpSocket clientSocket
QTcpSocket queueSocket
```

In my project, the server first send a message to the queue client. 
The message is:

"We can NOT accept a new client because we can NOT handle more than one". So, it knows what is the problem.

Then, the server closes the queue client socket.

We SHOULD close it because we do NOT want to handle lots of clients.

However, the main point is that we can work with clients in the queue and decide how to deal with them . I prefer to accept them just to inform and close them.

```
if (we have NOT a client) {
    work with clientSocket
}
else {
    queueSocket.wirte("We can NOT accept a new client because we can NOT handle more than one")
    close queueSocket
}
```

I hope it helps those who want to inform rejected clients.